# Why does a JavaScript event listener function need to be wrapped in function tags instead of just calling the function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

It has been awhile since I've worked in JavaScript and something just stumped me. I'm trying to call a function on an input change, but the function was running on page load only.

```
let textInput.document.getElementById('input');

textInput.addEventListener('input', myFunction());
```

Only runs on page load and doesn't seem to listen for the event at all. But

```
let textInput.document.getElementById('input');

textInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

works as expected. I have looked around trying to figure out why this is happening, but the docs that I've reviewed seem to indicate that I should be able to just call the myFunction() within the listener, without wrapping it in another function. Can someone explain to me what is going on here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a reference to a function followed immediately by `()`, that will execute the function at the time that the statement is evaluated. This is true no matter the context.

```
someFn(someOtherFn());
```

is equivalent to

```
const innerResult = someOtherFn();
someFn(innerResult);
```

`addEventListener` works the same way - it just has a slight extra complication that it takes more arguments. That's why `textInput.addEventListener('input', myFunction());` will run `myFunction` whenever the `addEventListener` line is executed.

> the docs that I've reviewed seem to indicate that I should be able to just call the myFunction() within the listener, without wrapping it in another function

This is true - you can pass *just the function itself*, without calling it:

```
textInput.addEventListener('input', myFunction)
```

Comment: So by adding the brackets, it will run once and only once? It wasn't picking up the events after the first run, but as soon as I wrapped it in another function it started acting as expected. Also, how would you pass parameters into the function if you can't include the brackets?

Comment: If you add `()`s after a function reference, *and* the line there only runs once, then yes, that function will only run once. If you need to pass parameters, you'll either need `.bind` or another function wrapper. `.addEventListener('input', () => fn('foo'))` or `.addEventListener('input', fn.bind(null, 'foo'))`

Comment: Weird, because I tried adding bind, but it still didn't work. Probably related to some other issue I guess. I'll mess around with it some more, and see if I can get it working with bind. I'm just glad to know that wrapping it in another function is a perfectly valid solution. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I have tried using bind, but I still can't get it working. `userInput.addEventListener('input', event => overload(document.getElementById('input').value, scriptOutput));` works, but `userInput.addEventListener('input', overload.bind(document.getElementById('input').value, scriptOutput));` does not. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't? The first param is a text input and the second is related to the function, changing the innerHTML of a div on the page to show the results of some calculations on the input value.

Comment: The first parameter to pass to `.bind` is the `this` value - that's why I passed `null` in the comment above. If you don't have one, pass `null`.

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work. I'll investigate in further detail later and see if I can spot what is wrong. I can post the whole codeblock if you're interested in seeing it.

Comment: Sure, it should be a trivial fix

Answer (score 2):

The function takes in the function as a variable, so in your case, just do `myFunction` instead of `myFunction()`. The way you are using it, the arguments provided to the listener are `input` and whatever your return value is from the function. using only `myFunction`, you provide the function as a value.

Comment: How would you include parameters in your function call then?

Comment: You cannot. The event listener runs the function during the time of the event. When the function runs, it gives you one provided parameter, the event. If you want to know more, google the eventlistener function from mozilla. You can, however acccess other declared variables and the contents of htmlElements.